# Two questions, How to create a survey result page in html? and how do i save user input from form in excel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel

I'm trying to have my HTML get info from users via form, and saves it to either excel or csv. and also have the user search for a keyword which will populate the info relating to the search in a table. I already have the form but i think i need either javascript or php.

I also want the site to have a survey where the user can see tallied results. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want fries with that?

Comment: If you want a good answer, it's generally best to give a good question.  Have you researched this topic at all before posting?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with php, but may be too complex. For your needs may be [Google Forms](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=de) a good alternative.